# Xcode 5 resignFirstResponder crash

Tags: objective-c, crash, uibutton

he scope is to have my keyboard dismissed when I press the addFirstOption related button.

This IBAction is a UIButton call in `MainViewController. firstOption` is a property IBOutlet UITextField.

The runtime crashes when it reaches  `[self.firstOption resignFirstResponder]`.
I tried  `[self.firstOption isFirstResponder]` and  `[self.firstOption canResignFirstResponder]` for a crosscheck and in both care I get a BOOL YES which make sense...

I did very similar and more simple code with the same input and resignFirstResponder and they all worked.

```
- (IBAction)addFirstOption:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *firstOptionName = [[self firstOption]text];
    Option *userOption1 = [[Option alloc]init];
    userOption1.name = firstOptionName;
    [self.firstOption resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: what kind of crash is it?  is there a backtrace that appears in the Xcode console?

Comment: Tnxs. It crashes at in the autoreleasepool main with this msg in the Log: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: Another thing I see here is that your "`userOption1`" will be immediately released, since it's not a property of your view controller nor is it an instance variable (ivar). Just for testing, take the two lines for "`userOption1`" out temporarily, and let me know if your crash goes away.

Comment: Done, but same problem. I tried to comment all the line as well except the self.firstOption resignFirstResponder but still the same...

Comment: One more thing I just thought of... check your UIButton in your storyboard or XIB file.  I think you might be connected to "`addFirstOption:`" ***and another action*** which doesn't exist anymore.  It should only be connected to one action.  Make certain of this.

Comment: It is connected only to MainViewController addFirstOption.

Comment: Michael, I fixed it by doing something similar to your suggestion. UIButton connections were ok. However the TextField had 2 connections: one to firstOption and the other from EditingDidEnd to ViewController. I deleted that and now it is working...